# Kill process started with ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, pid

1) I started a process with ShellExecuteEx

2) retrieve the PID with

```
GetProcessId(shellExInfo.hProcess)
```

Sample Code:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExInfo;

shellExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shellExInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shellExInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shellExInfo.lpVerb = "open";
shellExInfo.lpFile = processToStart.c_str();
shellExInfo.lpParameters = processParams.c_str();
shellExInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shellExInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
shellExInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&shellExInfo); // start process

GetProcessId(shellExInfo.hProcess); // retrieve PID
```

Now I want to kill the started process with given PID! How is this possible?

Thx

Comment: Use `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute/Ex()` to run executables. Not only is it the preferred API, but it also returns both the process ID and the process handle, so you don't have to call `GetProcessId()` manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but ShellExecute is a only way to run processes requires permission elevation ("runas" action).

Comment: @MonahTuk that is not entirely true. Although "runas" is the only *official* API to run an elevated process, there is an *unofficial* [`CreateProcessElevated()`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) API (and others) available on CodeProject, that utilizes the same elevation APIs that `ShellExecute()` uses internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To terminate a process you have to use the `TerminateProcess` function. However, it receives a handle to the process as a parameter:

```
TerminateProcess(shellExInfo.hProcess, 1);
```

If for some reason you store only the process id but not the handle, then you should open a handle first using the `OpenProcess` function:

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, process_id);
TerminateProcess(h, 1);
CloseHandle(h);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you close the process handle that `ShellExecuteEx()` returns, then you introduce a race condition if the process closes and its ID gets reused for a different process before you call `OpenProcess()`. So it is best to keep the process handle open until you are done using the process.